# Template Aliases - question (tour of c++)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I was going through the template Aliases from Tour of C++. I couldn't understand the below code and how to use it?

```
template<typename T>
class Vector {
public:
   using value_type = T; 
}
```

Here he is using the value_type as type alias for typename 'T', Why can't we just use the typename T, since we can pass any type to template(i.e. class Vector). What is the need to have alias for template?

```
template<typename C>
using Value_type = typename C::value_type;
```

Here how is value_type in the scope of C, i.e. how can we reference value_type with type 'C', since it is inside class "vector"?
does 'value_type' here mean its a Vector?
and 'Value_type' mean int::Vector or string::Vector etc..?

```
template<typename Container>
void algo(Container &c)
{
  Vector<Value_type<Container>> vec;
}
```

How are these three pieces linked?

Comment: i started writing an answer and then realized that I do not understand the last parts of your question ;). Please focus on one question per quesiton.

Comment: Yeah sure. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 5):

**Why a member alias?**

Consider you use an instantiation of `Vector` in some other generic code:

```
template <typename U>
void foo(const U& u);

Vector<int> v;
foo(v);
```

Then inside `foo` we would need to go through some hoops to find out that `T` is `int`. `foo` only knows about `U` which is `Vector<int>`. If `Vector<int>` has a `value_type` alias then it is much simpler to access that:

```
template <typename U>
void foo(const U& u) {
    using value_type = typename U::value_type;
    //...
}
```

Now `foo` does not need to care that `U::value_type` actually was the `T` parameter to `Vector` and is also fine with a type that is not an instantiation of a template:

```
struct OtherVector {
    using value_type = int;
};
OtherVector ov;
foo(ov);
```

---

**No member alias: "some hoops"**

Using a member alias is the simple way. For the sake of completeness I want to show the complicated way that lets `foo` infer `T` from `Vector<T>`. You'll have to bear with me...

First, note that function templates cannot be partially specialized. Thats why I introduce a level of indirection:

```
template <typename U>
struct foo_impl {
    void operator()(const U& u) {
        std::cout << "Hello \n";
    } 
};

template <typename U>
void foo(const U& u) { foo_impl<U>{}(u); }
```

Caller will call `foo` and in the background we can mess around with `foo_impl`.
For example we can add a partial specilization for `Vector<T>` where we can directly have access to `T`:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo_impl< Vector<T> > {
    void operator()(const Vector<T>& v) {
        std::cout << "Hello Vector<T>\n";
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int,T>) {
            std::cout << "T == int\n";
        }
    }
};
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/qvfded).

However, consider what that means for `foo`. The `foo` above is fine with any type that has a `value_type` alias. Now we have a rather boring general definition (prints `"Hello"`) and a specialization for `Vector<T>` (that prints more when `T==int`). Thats quite a restriction if we want `foo` to also work with a

```
 template <typename T>
 struct Bar {};
```

What can we do? We can provide a more generic specialization that matches also instantiations of `Bar`:

```
template <template<class> class A, class T>
struct foo_impl< A<T> > {
    void operator()(const A<T>& v) {
        std::cout << "Hello A<T>\n";
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int,T>) {
            std::cout << "T == int\n";  // We know what T is when a Vector<T> is passed !!
        }
    }
};
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/TM1sjs)

It is using a template tempalte parameter to match any instantiation of a template with a single template parameter.

Are we fine now? Unfortunately no, because suppose we want to get a "value type"  from this:

```
template <typename A,typename B>
struct Moo {};
```

Suppose by convention the first parameter, `A`, is the value type we are looking for. Then we need to add an even more generic specialization:

```
template <template<class...> class A, typename T,typename... Others>
struct foo_impl< A<T,Others...> > {
    void operator()(const A<T,Others...>& v) {
        std::cout << "Hello A<T>\n";
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int,T>) {
            std::cout << "T == int\n"; 
        }
    }
};
```

[Live Example](https://godbolt.org/z/PY7ovh)

This will match an instantiation of a template with any number of type parameters and will detect the first template parameter to be `T`.

Are we fine yet? Unfortunately: Not at all.
The above does not match a

```
template <typename A, int x>
struct Omg {};
```

Because it has a non-type template parameter. We could also fix that, but lets stop here. Requiring that a value type is always the first parameter is too restrictive anyhow.

*TL;DR*

What we actually want is to make `foo` work with any type that has an associated "value type". And the simple way to do that is that any type that should be passed to `foo` to supply a member alias called `value_type`.

Comment: Purely editorial suggestion: "*`foo` only knows about `U` which is `Vector<int>`*" might be unfortunate statement as from `foo` point of view it doesn't know about `int`. This is the essence of the issue.

Comment: @bloody sorry I don't get your point. What I exluded from the answer, because I think it would add too much complexity, is to show how `foo` could infer `int` from `Vector<int>`. Finding out if a type is an isntantiation of a template and finding out what the first template parameter is is possible.

Comment: @bloody In other words: "from foo point of view it doesn't know about int." thats not correct.

Comment: @bloody maybe adding that would make the answer more clear, though I am waiting for OPs edit to the quesiton.

Comment: What I meant is `foo` doesn't know about `int` from `U` itself - this is why `value_type` is helpful. For me the phrase *only knows* in connection with *which is `vector<int>'* just sounds a bit contradictory. But I get your point, that's just purely linguistic opinion...

Comment: @bloody yes I think I understand what you meant now and you are wrong. `foo` can infer `int` from its `Vector<int>` parameter. As OPs edit seems to take longer I am considering to just add it to the answer and then call it an answer. I can ping you if you are interested

Comment: Yea, neverminds. By the way - what is that alternative inferring method of "internal" template type (without `value_type`) since we're right talking about that :) ??

Comment: @bloody Thats what I was talking about all the time. I am going to add it, will just take a minute or two

Comment: Yea, yea! I've just realized a second before your last reply. Sorry for missing that point. I'll wait for edit then :)

Comment: @bloody there you go. It is *possible*, but nobody really wants to do it unless necessary, thats why I wrote "Then inside foo we would need to go through some hoops to find out that T is int. foo only knows about U which is Vector<int>" :)

Comment: @bloody actually I don't know if all of my answer is still relevant for OPs question, but I had my fun :P

Comment: Some linguistic sense of my original remark is still valid but don't bother ;) Nonetheless I appreciate the update, thanks from my side. I'm perusing it now.